# Using Linear Actuator as 'Coilgun'

Tags: electromagnetism, coil, magnetics, linear, actuator

If One were to have a Linear Actuator like shown below, could you efficiently use that coil as an accelerator for said Coil gun or Magnetic Linear Accelerator.

[image: Actuator from a pinball machine]

I use the picture above as it is out of a pinball machine. The flipper from a pinball machine hits pretty hard. Could i for example take one and just use the rod in the center as a projectile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, yes. Remove the spring, and make sure to deactivate the coil fast enough so that the field collapses when the rod is moving the fastest it can get. Or put a non-ferrous marble where the rod is so that the rod hits the marble and that becomes the projectile.

A coil gun is nothing but carefully timed solenoids.

Comment: Good Answer, I will read about the Marble, sounds like a good idea i never though of. Will Best Answer ASAP.

Comment: Also, I could cast my own marbles out of Aluminum cans I believe, but they wont be a perfect sphere.